# What does array * string mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was looking through some Rails source code and came across

```
# File vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/builder/css.rb, line 129
129:     def target!
130:       @target * ''
131:     end
```

What does the * '' do? Is that multiplication by an empty string...? And why would you do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bizarre syntax. These are equivalent:

```
>> [1, 2, 3] * 'joiner'
=> "1joiner2joiner3"

>> [1, 2, 3].join 'joiner'
=> "1joiner2joiner3"
```

so in this case it joins all the entries of `@target` into one string, with nothing between the entries.

Note: if you do something like `[1, 2, 3] * 3` (using an `int` instead of a `str`), you'll get three concatenated copies of the array instead.

Answer (score 6):

It does the same thing as:

```
["foo","bar","baz"].join
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002210

Per Z.E.D.'s suggestion, you would use it if you want to confuse people and make your code more error prone.

Comment: I'd probably word that differently. It results in the same thing as an [].join, but using the join() method is more obvious and more commonly used. I've seen several recommendations that we don't use the '*' operator with arrays because so few people use it that it is confusing. Compare the output of [1,2] * ',' with [1,2] * 2 for an example of why it doesn't play nice with our brains.

Comment: Are you arguing that it doesn't do the same thing?  The RDoc says "equivalent to".  Readability is orthogonal to implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Really cryptic code indeed.

After checking the source code, I realized that `@target` is actually an `Array` instance, I know you can do stuff like this

```
[5] * 5 # => [5,5,5,5,5]
```

I don't know where `Array#*` is defined (maybe in `ActiveSupport`), but what I can tell you is that, this is the behaviour when it gets multiplied by a `String`

```
[1,2,3] * 'comma' # => "1comma2comma3"
[1,2,3] * '' # => '123'
```

So I can infer it is concatanating all the elements of the array without any separators.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#*`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000743) with a `String` argument is equivalent to `Array#join`.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments:

1. Having a ! end a method name implies that it's a mutating operation, which this example doesn't seem to be.
2. As others have stated it's indeed cryptic. I would go for @target.to_s or @target.join

Comment: Additionally, this type of ruby code makes me sad because ruby is  easy to read and idiomatically beautiful, and syntax like this gives me Perl flashbacks.

Comment: You are the second person on this question to complain about the infix operator syntax. I don't quite get it. With the exception of Lisp and Forth, pretty much *every* programming language on the planet has a `*` infix operator. There's nothing "bizarre" or "sad" about infix operators.

Comment: Of course, but this example makes one have to think briefly to get the line of code. Creating an empty string to concatenate an array is a little obscure use of *. I have absolutely nothing against the operator.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I'd see someone wanting to use `*` to join an array of strings is if they want to avoid the word `join`, which is also used on threads.

With the following:

```
strings = ["John", "Smith"]
threads = [Thread.new{puts "hai"}, Thread.new{ puts "world!"}]
strings.join(" ") # Legit
threads.each {|thread| thread.join} # Legit
```

you could make the mistake of doing

```
threads.join # Not legit, but won't raise an error
```

If you replaced `strings.join` with `strings.*`, then you'd have fewer `join`s in your code. Now you could do a `grep` for them, and check that each one is being done to a thread, not to an array. In fact, you could choose to make `Array#join` throw an exception.