# Why can one multiply string with int with block as closure in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

While reading the book *Programming Ruby*, one example shows how blocks can be used as closure:

```
def nTimes(aThing)
  return proc {|n| aThing * n}
end

p = nTimes("Hello ")
```

Now if we output the value of `p.call(3)` , it would be `Hello Hello Hello`

However, if our code was simply `puts 3 * "Hello "` , Ruby would complain about incompatible type.

Why? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `puts "Hello " * 3`?

Comment: Oh I'm so embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: Eh, I don't really know Ruby; I just noticed that apples weren't being compared to apples. That said, it would be interesting to see an explanation of why it doesn't work both ways in Ruby... it does in Python.

Comment: It's probably just a philosophical (read: random) choice on the part of the language designers...

Comment: I think it's because string is a larger type than int. So if you put string before int it would convert int to string, whereas the other way it's not allowed.

Comment: You can also multiply an [array with a string, and an array with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233575/what-does-string-array-mean-in-ruby/2233605#2233605)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with closures or blocks. It is related to how operators are handled in Ruby.

On binary operations like `*` and `+`, **the object to the left of the operand is the receiver of the method**. So when you do `"hello " * 3` it calls the `*` method on the class `String` and passes `3` as a parameter. The definition of `String#*` takes integers as parameters and returns `self` repeated that many times, hence the output `"hello hello hello "`.

But if you phrase it as `3 * "hello "`, the `*` method of the `Fixnum` class is called, and `"hello "` is passed as a parameter. `Fixnum#*` doesn't know what to do with `String` parameters so you get an error.

Comment: Thank you! I realized it shortly after reading the first comment under my question. But your explanation is definitely more precise.

Comment: :) I figured this is a common pitfall for people learning Ruby (I have gone through the same a few years back) Maybe it will help others who search for similar questions.